# Unity3d (C#) player won't teleport with new Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever my player touches an object called "LevelEnd1" I want it to teleport the player to a specific set of coordinates and send a message to the console, but all my code does is send a message to the console. (there are no errors / I set the GameObject variable to the Player)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTouched : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    public void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LevelEnd1")
        {
            Player.transform.position = new Vector3(-193.5f, 5.860001f, 803.13f);
            Debug.Log("it worked!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is something maybe overwriting the position somewhere else?

Comment: i tried removing the console message from the if statement, and nothing appears in the console

Comment: Well .. then who or what is (supposed to be) calling that `OnControllerColliderHit` method? It apparently doesn't ..

Comment: It's a script called Player Touched inside my player model, and it's called when the player touches a gameobject called Level1End.

Comment: The only other vector3 I use is in the Player Movement script

`Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;`

Comment: If as you say there is no log appearing in the console.. then it isn't called

Comment: Instead of using `OnControllerColliderHit` (which I've never knew existed after over a decade of working with Unity), have you tried using `OnCollisionEnter` instead? `OnControllerColliderHit` seems to be a very specific use case when using the `CharacterController` provided by Unity.

Comment: OnControllerColliderHit works fine (the print code still works it's just the teleport code) / the same thing happened with OnCollisionEnter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my movement script was constantly changing my position, so I disabled my player's movement for 0.1 seconds before teleporting.

Player Touched code:

```
public void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "LevelEnd1")
        {
            StartCoroutine("Teleport");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Teleport()
    {
        playerMovement.disabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        Player.transform.position = new Vector3(-193.5f, 5.860001f, 803.13f);
        Debug.Log("it worked!!");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        playerMovement.disabled = false;
    }
```

Player Movement code:

```
public bool disabled = false;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0 && !disabled)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        if (move.magnitude > 1 && !disabled)
            move /= move.magnitude;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```